# How to fetch the Finance Charge Preferences values using SuiteScript in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We need to perform calculations in SuiteScript using the values in Setup/Accounting/Finance Charge Preferences. Which record is this stored on? Specifically, we're looking for these finance charge fields:

- Annual Rate
- Minimum Finance Charge
- Grace Period

We've tried to create saved searches in all of the obvious records but have not been able to find these fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not documented but `N/runtime` can be used to get this info (at least in the console)

```js
require(['N/runtime'], runtime=>{
    const user = runtime.getCurrentUser();
    console.log(user.getPreference({
        name:'FC_GRACEPERIOD'
    }));
});
```

You can get the field ids by clicking the field help on the Finance Charge Preferences page.

If that doesn't work to get the fields you can see if the fields are available but not documented by creating a server side script (I'd use a suitelet) to get the accounting preferences object and dump the field names.

If the config module was available client side this would be the console version:

```js
require(['N/config'], config=>{
    const conf = config.load({type:'accountingpreferences'});
    conf.getFields().forEach(f=>console.log(f));
});
```

Comment: This worked for FC_GRACEPERIOD and FC_MINIMUM, but not annualrate. Any ideas?

Comment: Unable to find annualrate using any of the methods above.